# Google auth seems broken

Tags: support, login, google, authentication

I can't seem to login using my Google account. Luckily I still have an active session on the main things I care about but when I log into anything with my Google auth, I get:

> There was an error fetching your account from Google. Please try logging in again.

I do see the auth listed in my profile and it is still authorized on the Google side.

Halp!